# Oracle: save fixed length file style output to a variable

Tags: sql, oracle

In an Oracle function, I'm trying to return a CLOB that contains a section of what will be written out to a file.
I need to take rows from my select statement and pad the values (I get how to use LPAD to do this) and have each one be a line in the result

So, if I have a table looking like:

```
col1  col2  col3
this  is    data
and   a     gain
b           b
```

And I run it through my function:

```
FUNCTION create_file_section() RETURN CLOB IS
BEGIN

  --SELECT col1, col2, col3 values from table and LPAD them and concat them together,

END;
```

I'd get the output like (assuming I want to pad to 4 chars):

```
this00isdata
0and000again
000b0000000b
```

Comment: If you know how to lpad, what is your question? Do you want a single CLOB with each row from your table as a separate line in the CLOB? What is the maximum length of each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each padded line will be less than 4000 characters, you can do the padding and concatenation as part of the query. Then you need to loop over the result set and append each line to the CLOB. Something like:

```
FUNCTION create_file_section() RETURN CLOB IS
  l_clob CLOB;
BEGIN
  dbms_lob.createtemporay(l_clob, false);
  for r in (
    select lpad(col1, 4, '0') || lpad(col2, 4, '0')
      || lpad(col3, 4, '0') || chr(10) as values
    from your_table
  )
  loop
    dbms_lob.append(l_clob, r.values);
  end loop;

  return l_clob;
END create_file_section;
/
```

I've included a newline character in the concatenated value, but you could do that in the append instead if you prefer. You may also need a carriage return, depending on your platform.

If you are going to write this to a file at some point then having it in an intermediate CLOB probably isn't necessary - it would be simpler to go straight from the query and write to the file in the loop; which would also let you get platform-specific line terminators automatically, via `utl_file.new_line`.